# Power Bi: limit slicer to values that exist in fact table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I have 1 Fact Table Tbl_Import in my Pbix-file that is linked with an automatic generated calendartable.

I used a slicer and a table.  The slicer is showing too much options.  The first date in Tbl_Import is 16/12/2022, but in the slicer I have all the other months also.

Is there a way to limit the slicer options to the actual dates in the facttable?

I am using Power Bi Desktop (without Premium).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Create a measure which is

```
Measure = COUNTROWS(Tbl_Import)
```

Add the measure as a visual filter to the slicer with it restricted to showing a count > 0.

[image]